# Can I set content of before to original value?

Tags: css

So I've been trying to set content of before pseudo element to original's element value

```
div::before{
content:initial
}
```

but my style only works with `content: ""`

it it possible? I don't want to involve js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JS, I don't believe you can get the content of an element with CSS. However, if you have control over the markup, you can take the content and also add it to a `data` attribute.

You can then use the `attr(data-attr-name)` to get that content:

```css
div::before {
content: attr(original-content);
}
```

```html
<div original-content="this is a test">
   this is a test
</div>
```